# C# Access denied for any folder

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

When i selected any folder in

> FolderDialogBrowser

i got error about access denied for folder. That's for everything folders, documents, my computer, desktop etc, really every folder. I was read about user access for folders (but every folder on disk?), and run as administrator, but it don't help me. If i send me program to friend, they will have too play with folders access to select path? I'm logged on admin account and i have all permissions, but my program no.

```cs
/*
 * Created by SharpDevelop.
 * User: Tomek
 * Date: 2019-04-05
 * Time: 04:26
 * 
 * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard Headers.
 */
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace meta_generator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
            InitializeComponent();

            //
            // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
            //
        }

        OpenFileDialog files = new OpenFileDialog();
        FolderBrowserDialog metaOutput = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        string metapath;

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            files.Filter = "Wszystkie pliki (*.*)|*.*";
            files.Multiselect = true;

            if (files.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                foreach (String file in files.FileNames)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ";" + file;
                }
            }
        }

        void Button2Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            metaOutput.Description = "Wybierz folder gdzie zostanie wygenerowany plik meta.xml";
            metaOutput.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments;

            if (metaOutput.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                metapath = metaOutput.SelectedPath;
                textBox2.Text = metapath;
            }
        }
        void Button3Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0 && textBox2.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                XDocument meta = new XDocument(new XElement("meta"));

                foreach (String file in files.FileNames)
                {
                    XElement childFileTag = new XElement("file");
                    XAttribute sourcepath = new XAttribute("src", file);
                    childFileTag.Add(sourcepath);

                    meta.Root.Add(childFileTag);
                }

                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                    meta.Root.Add(new XElement("oop", "true"));

                meta.Save(metapath);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: @mjwills ```meta.Save(metapath + @"\bob.xml");``` Works, thanks. I was think meta.Save function get only path for save file, but i wasn't think about filename and extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your use of

```
meta.Save(metapath);
```

`metapath` is a **folder** (directory) name (like `c:\temp\`, not a filename (like `c:\temp\bob.xml`).

When saving a file, you need to save to a complete path (including filename). An example would be:

```
meta.Save(Path.Combine(metapath, "bob.xml"));
```

*Alternatively, don't use `FolderBrowserDialog` - instead use `SaveFileDialog` to allow the user to choose their own filename.*